# How to programmatically find the socket waiting queue size of my computer?

Tags: c, bash, sockets, netcat

I want to programmatically find the size of the socket waiting queue of my computer i.e. the number of socket that can be put in the queue before being refused (while the server is listening for clients).

On the server side, I simply create a socket, bind it, listen and enter in an infinite loop in order to wait client sockets.
Then I thought that this little script would help me to find the queue size:

```
pids=""
for i in {1..8}; do
     netcat localhost -w 3 19677 &
     pids+=" $!"
done

for p in $pids; do
        if wait $p; then
                echo "Process $p success"
       else
                echo "Process $p fail"
        fi
done
```

If there is more than 4 rounds in the loop then I always get a timeout exception,(and never for 4 or less) but increasing the number of rounds doesn't always lead to more errors (I don't always get 2 errors for 6 rounds, 3 for 7, etc.). Why?

Moreover, if I launch netcat directly in 5 terminals (`netcat localhost -w 5 19677`), I don't get any error.

What am I missing?

Comment: `listen` has an argument, do you know what it means?

Comment: I presume that you're talking about the backlog argument. I set this argument at 1, but as it is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111040/listen-ignores-the-backlog-argument it  is only advisory. (If I have well understood obviously.)

Comment: If you are not talking about the backlog, then what?

Comment: Hum, I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand your question. I set a backlog of 1, but I still can accept more than one connection (at least 4) in the queue. Unless my script is badly testing it (likely).

Comment: You set the backlog to *at least* one, and can establish *at least* one connection. No problem here.

Comment: Ok, it is a minimum, I now understand better. But what I would like to do is find the maximum, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think a reliable maximum exists.

Comment: According to the EJP response it does not seem that the backlog argument is a minimum since it can be adjusted down by the platform. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have never seen it adjusted down, but perhaps this can happen. Then you cannot obtain any reliable information about the queue size. Why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: @n.m. Try setting it to 0x7fffffff and you will see it adjusted down all right, although the only way to discover it would be by peeking the kernel somehow.

Comment: @EJP well the man page does say it will be truncated to `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`, I mean anything beyond that.

Comment: @n.m. I don't know what 'anything beyond that' means. It will certainly be truncated to the value given in that location. What makes you think there is any other limit?

Comment: @EJP I mean it will be truncated to /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn as per the man page, but I haven't seen it truncated more than that.

Comment: @n.m. I am unable to understand your point. Did somebody say it would be truncated more than that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this. You could remember the argument you supplied to `listen()`, but as the platform can adjust it either up or down it won't do you much good.

What happens when the backlog is exceeded is platform-dependent. Windows will issue connection refusals; other platforms will do nothing, which will lead to retries and possible connection timeouts.

Comment: That's why I would like to test how many connections can get on the waiting queue. Why the way I tested it don't always show the same results on the same platform?

Comment: I'm running the script on Debian and with a timeout so why don't I always get the same number of connection timeout with the same number of connection tries?

Comment: What happens in the server's infinite loop?

Comment: Nothing, just a `for(;;){ }` in order to avoid the end of the program.