# Does listen's backlog number include SYN-received connections count in case of TCP in Linux?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I read some posts and checked Linux kernel code like `inet_listen()`->[`inet_csk_listen_start()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3.6/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L795) and it seems that **`backlog` argument of `listen()` syscall only affects on accepted queue**, but not on SYN-received queue:

```
sk->sk_max_ack_backlog = backlog;
```

I.e. symbolically *`accept-queue + syn-received-queue != backlog`*.
I can't figure out what is happening. [This article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/syn-packet-handling-in-the-wild/) states:

> The maximum allowed length of both the Accept and SYN Queues is taken
>   from the backlog parameter passed to the listen(2) syscall by the
>   application.

But there is nothing similar in [MAN page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html).

Also in case of Linux: Is `backlog` a hint as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111040/listen-ignores-the-backlog-argument) or it really limits queues?

Comment: The userspace `listen()` function and the underlying actual syscall are not specific to IP sockets.  Naturally, their documentation does not speak to details specific to the kernel's IP implementation.

Comment: It's system-dependent. Your link atates that it is about Linix.

Comment: @user207421 Yep, that's about Linux implementation. Fixed title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of 4.3 kernel you specified it's something like:

`tcp_v4_do_rcv()`->`tcp_rcv_state_process()`->`tcp_v4_conn_request()`->`tcp_conn_request()`->`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_is_full()`

[Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3.6/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6151) we can see the most important details about queues:

```
/* TW buckets are converted to open requests without
 * limitations, they conserve resources and peer is
 * evidently real one.
 */
if ((sysctl_tcp_syncookies == 2 ||
     inet_csk_reqsk_queue_is_full(sk)) && !isn) {
    want_cookie = tcp_syn_flood_action(sk, skb, rsk_ops->slab_name);
    if (!want_cookie)
        goto drop;
}

/* Accept backlog is full. If we have already queued enough
 * of warm entries in syn queue, drop request. It is better than
 * clogging syn queue with openreqs with exponentially increasing
 * timeout.
 */
if (sk_acceptq_is_full(sk) && inet_csk_reqsk_queue_young(sk) > 1) {
    NET_INC_STATS_BH(sock_net(sk), LINUX_MIB_LISTENOVERFLOWS);
    goto drop;
}
```

Pay your attention to `inet_csk_reqsk_queue_is_full()`:

```
static inline int inet_csk_reqsk_queue_is_full(const struct sock *sk)
{
    return inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk) >= sk->sk_max_ack_backlog;
}
```

Finally it compares current queue `icsk_accept_queue` with `sk_max_ack_backlog` size which was previously set by `inet_csk_listen_start()`. So yep, **`backlog` affects incoming queue** in current case.

You can see that both `sk_acceptq_is_full()` and `inet_csk_reqsk_queue_is_full()` make comparison with the same socket's `sk_max_ack_backlog` which is set through the `listen()`:

```
static inline bool sk_acceptq_is_full(const struct sock *sk)
{
    return sk->sk_ack_backlog > sk->sk_max_ack_backlog;
}
```

Useful links: [1](https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/09/syn-cookies.html), [2](http://veithen.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html)